# Unable to access SSH using Putty to Arvixe shared hosting

Tags: ssh, cpanel, web-hosting, vps, shared-hosting

I am deploying my PHP web application on shared hosting. I want SSH access and I tried to enable it and tried to access from Putty, but it is not working.

I access to SSH Access section from C Panel:

[image]

Then I entered to manage SSH and generated SSH keys pair and downloaded private key and authorized the public key as below.

[image]

Then I tried to access from putty importing downloaded private key, like this:

[image]

[image]

Then I created user from user manager like this:

[image]

When I login from Putty, it is giving me this error:

[image]

Why can I not access SSH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH Access to a cPanel must be enabled at the WHM level in the first place.  You should contact your host and see if they offer Shell access (which for cPanel is usually "JailShell" access.)

If that is enabled, you need to use PuTTYGen to generate a key for PuTTY from the downloaded key that you downloaded.  Since you're using WinSCP, try this: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen

Comment: What is WHM please? I am newbie to deployment process.

Comment: WHM = the master control panel that assigns cPanels to clients (Web Host Manager).  If jailshell isn't enabled on the host system, you can't get shell access.

Comment: Thanks. So we dont have accesa to WHM even we are using dedicated server? And only web host master has accesa to it. Is it ?

Comment: Do you have a login for root?  Are you sure it's a real dedicated server?

Comment: No, I am using shared hosting. But I wonder about WHM,For dedicated server, sometimes we got access to WHM?

Comment: If you are using shared hosting, you must ask you host if you have jailshell